# Combinatorics: Display all arrangements

Tags: python

I am trying to find a way to display all arrangements of n blue coins and m red coins programmatically. I know the answer is n+m C n, but I want the computer to show me all n+m C n arrangements. Just to clarify, if n and m are both 2, the output that the computer should give is this: `["bbrr", "brbr", "brrb", "rbbr", "rbrb", "rrbb"]`. Also, the code should be in Python if possible. If you don't have Python, it will still work since I know many languages. I have tried using itertools, but it doesn't work since each red coin is counted as different. I have tried researching a lot about distinguishability in Python and found nothing. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because aside from this lacking any basic research or attempt, this is also something that can be found in the python standard library if your try to look for it for a couple of minutes.

Comment: Please post what you have attempted so far.

Comment: This is a reasonable question.  The standard library option, *itertools.combinations* doesn't help here because the inputs have duplicated values and the library function assumes distinct inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `itertools` package has what you are asking for.  However, it will consider identical items to be separate entities, so we can use `set()` to clean up the duplicates

```
from itertools import permutations

sorted(set(x for x in permutations('rrbb', 4)))

[('b', 'b', 'r', 'r'),
 ('b', 'r', 'b', 'r'),
 ('b', 'r', 'r', 'b'),
 ('r', 'b', 'b', 'r'),
 ('r', 'b', 'r', 'b'),
 ('r', 'r', 'b', 'b')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic recursive solution in Haskell.

```
arrangements :: (Integral n, Integral m) => n -> m -> [String]
arrangements n 0 = [stimes n "b"]
arrangements 0 m = [stimes m "r"]
arrangements n m = (('b' :) <$> arrangements (n - 1) m) 
                <> (('r' :) <$> arrangements n (m - 1))

λ> arrangements 2 2
["bbrr","brbr","brrb","rbbr","rbrb","rrbb"]

λ> arrangements 2 3
["bbrrr","brbrr","brrbr","brrrb","rbbrr","rbrbr","rbrrb","rrbbr","rrbrb","rrrbb"]
```

Answer (score -1):

lets create a recursive function for this purpose,

f(0, 0, currentStr) = currentStr

f(n, m, currentStr) = f(n-1, m, currentStr + "b") and f(n, m-1, currentStr + "r")

Comment: m and n go negative and this never terminates. You need to consider the two base cases where n=0 and m=0 separately.